# When I am trying to get data by using VERTX HTTP CLIENT its giving me null

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

Hi Can anybody please have look :

When I am trying to get data by using VERTX HTTP CLIENT its giving me null pointer exception  in last line and same URL provide data when I used java HTTP CLIENT :

```
HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions().setKeepAlive(false);

options.setLogActivity(true);    
options.setDefaultHost("http://delvmpllbbab10");
options.setDefaultPort(7003);

HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(options);
HttpClientResponse[] clientResponse = {null};

client.request(HttpMethod.GET, "/rcsservices/homePage", response -> {
    System.out.println("Received response with status code " + response.statusCode());

    clientResponse[0] = response;

}).putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end(clientResponse[0].toString());
```

Is this code I have some issue...

Answer (score 0):

That is correct you will get a `NPE`, so in your code you initialize the `clientResponse` variable with `{ null }`. If you now follow how the code is executed you will see why:

1. create a request object: `client.request(`
2. you configure what will be executed once the response is received: `response -> { ... }
3. you add a header to the request: `putHeader(...)`
4. you trigger the request `end(clientResponse[0].toString())`

Now you see that `clientResponse[0]` is still null (that was the value you initialized it. So what is happening is that you're calling:

```
null.toString()
```

Which is invalid and will always throw a `Null Pointer Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as I started to use Vert-X framework and I can notice the following improvements from your code:

1. You  have to process the response with the bodyHandler of the HttpClientResponse, then you cannot feed an external variable unless final
2. It is always better to use the asyncResponse in order not to block the calling thread, especially if you rely on external system (another Web-service in your case)
3. I am not sure you want to give a body or not, the `.end()` at the request contains the new "client request body" but as you make a GET, the body must be null
4. Try to use the standard `HttpHeaders` and `MediaType` (I personally use `MediaType` from JAX-RS) instead writing your own strings.
5. Try to use a proper Logger instead `System.out.println(...)`

The following code shows how I manage to return the response to the original caller:

```
public void callWebService(@Context HttpServerRequest request, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {

    HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions().setKeepAlive(false);

    options.setLogActivity(true);    
    options.setDefaultHost("http://delvmpllbbab10");
    options.setDefaultPort(7003);

    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(options);

    client.request(HttpMethod.GET, "/rcsservices/homePage", response -> {

        System.out.println("Received response with status code " + response.statusCode());
        int code = response.statusCode();
        if (code == 200) {
            response.bodyHandler(bufferResponse -> {
                // Adapt according your response type, could be String as well
                JsonObject httpResult = bufferResponse.toJsonObject();
                System.out.println("Received HTTP response with body " + httpResult);
                asyncResponse.resume(Response.ok(httpResult).build());
            });
        } else {

            response.bodyHandler(bufferResponse -> {
                // Return null in a JSON Object in case of error
                String httpResult = "{null}";
                asyncResponse.resume(Response.status(code).entity(httpResult).build());
            });
        }

}).putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).end();
```

There are plenty of ways to do the same thing, and you can check the [official manual page](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_writing_http_servers_and_clients).